# Transposing Excel through vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, transpose

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I have exported from some other program.

It has rows that are colored based on few business conditions.

Now I have to transpose the whole excel sheet along with the colors and formatting.

Please note that I have to do this using Vbscript only.

This is the code I've written so far, but this transposes without the formatting:

```
 sub transpose
 On Error Resume Next
 Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 objExcel.Visible = False
 objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
 set table = ActiveDocument.GetSheetObject( "CH01" )
 CellRect = ActiveDocument.GetApplication().GetEmptyRect()
 CellRect.Top = 0
 CellRect.Left = 0
 CellRect.Width = table.GetColumnCount
 CellRect.Height = table.GetRowCount
 set CellMatrix = table.GetCells( CellRect )
 for RowIter=CellRect.Top to CellRect.Width-1
   for ColIter=CellRect.Left to CellRect.Height-1
     ObjExcel.Cells(RowIter+1, ColIter+1).Value = CellMatrix(ColIter)(RowIter).Text
    'msgbox(CellMatrix(ColIter)(RowIter).Text)
   next
 next
 objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\Documents and    Settings\prasanna\Desktop\test3.xls")
 objExcel.Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and           Settings\prasanna\Desktop\test3.xls")
 objExcel.Application.Visible = True
 objExcel = Nothing
 end sub
```

Comment: First, explain us why you can use VBScript only (are you sure you are not confusing with VBA?). Second, show us [what you have already tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and where you are stuck so that we could help you. As stated, your question leads nowhere

Comment: I have to use vbscript only becasue the tool I am talking about allows me to use only Vbscript

Comment: Are you sure you do not mean VBA? The version of Visual Basic built in to Excel?  VBScript is not part of Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew.., this costed some time and experimenting, here a working solution for office 2012

```
const xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats = 12 'doesn't work with Excel 2010 ?
const xlFormats =-4122
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = false
```

if you allready have your target xls you can skip these lines

```
Set wbkDest = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
wbkDest.saveAs "c:\test2.xls"
wbkDest.close
```

and go on here

```
Set objWorkbook1= objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test1.xls")
Set objWorkbook2= objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test2.xls")
objWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy
'we have to do the paste twice, once for the values, once for the formats
objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlFormats
objWorkbook1.save
objWorkbook2.save
objWorkbook1.close
objWorkbook2.close
set objExcel=nothing
```

Comment: The `PasteSpecial` routine has a `Transpose` parameter, which will mean the transpose will occur when pasted.

Comment: Thank u very much it did the trick I wanted...It'll be of gr8 help if u can let me know hw u found the value -4122.

Comment: @user1472309: i record a macro and then translate to vbscript. to get the values of constants you do a google search on eg "const xlformats". Could you please accept the answer ?